# How to make one of child view of nestedscrollview to sticky header?

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is my code snipet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:context="com.ajinkyabadve.mywatchlist.movie_detail_new.MovieActivity">    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/retryLayoutNoInternet"
        layout="@layout/no_internet_retry_layout"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/poster"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/poster_of_movie"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include
        android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/content_movie" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieOrignalTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="subtitle"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And below is content_movie.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_movie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ajinkyabadve.mywatchlist.movie_detail_new.MovieActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_movie">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/overview" />

        <include layout="@layout/cast" />

        <include layout="@layout/facts" />


<!-- Below tablayout I want to work as a sticky header -->
        <!--<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="100dp"-->
        <!--android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />--> </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The commented tablayout should work as a sticky header(meaning it should not scroll when it reaches to top while scrolling).How to achive this  effect using the coordinate layout?OR In any other way.Can we use custom behavior or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following library to achieve this effect.

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

This is basically a custom scroll view and within this scroll view you can make any child view or layout as sticky by adding the tag:

`android:tag="sticky"`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yup it works thanks. But its using the scroll view just copy past the code from lib and extend using Nestedscrollview.

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is move the `TabLayout` to the `AppBarLayout`.

Since the `TabLayout` doesn't have scroll flags defined, it will stick to the top of the layout when you scroll.

When you do this, the app bar height needs to be changed to `wrap_content` and the 400dp height needs to go to the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

I just took the `AppBarLayout` snippet from your entire XML to demonstrate:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/poster_of_movie"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: the tablayout and viewpager should  end to the nested scroll view and when  we scroll up it should stick below the toolbar.In this case its always show below the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your **Toolbar** inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinate"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
             tools:context="com.ajinkyabadve.mywatchlist.movie_detail_new.MovieActivity">    

 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/retryLayoutNoInternet"
    layout="@layout/no_internet_retry_layout"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/poster_of_movie"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movieTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"               android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movieOrignalTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="subtitle"
                     android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Su       btitle.Inverse" />
    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
 <include
    android:id="@+id/content"
    layout="@layout/content_movie" />
```